# How can I use a closure for my angular controller?

Tags: angularjs, asynchronous, closures

I'm trying to setup my angular controllers in the format of closures. But Im having issues with asynchronous behavior. Basically whats returned is an undefined value on the controller.

```
myApp.controller(['RoleController', RoleController]);

var RoleController = function (MockRest, $scope) {
    var roleValues = [];
    var setRoleValues = (function () { 
        return MockRest.getRoles().then(function(data) {
            var formattedData = data.plain();
            return Immutable.fromJS(formattedData);
        });
    })(); 

    return { 
       displayRowCollection: setRoleValues,
       roleValues: roleValues, 

    }
};
```

Comment: Are you able to reproduce the issue you're having in a JSFiddle?

Comment: I don't believe you can do it this way.  Further, how would you handle dependency injection? Just curious - why are you trying to do it this way?

Comment: It works fine, for dependency injection those are passed in the controller function. I havent had issue returning synchronous values its only async.